# Validating :inclusion in rails based on parent Model's attribute value

Tags: validation, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two models `Project` and 'Task` where project has_many tasks and task belongs to project

Now in my `Task` model I am doing validation on a field using attributes in the project

```
validates :effort, :inclusion => 1..(project.effort)
```

This results in an error `method_missing: undefined method project`

Question is, how can I validate a child attribute (Task.effort) based on a parent's attribute's value (Project.effort) in Rails 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up doing the validation in a callback and throwing an exception if it is not valid. The only drawback is that the controller has to catch the exception.

> **UPDATE**
>
> A better solution based on rails 3.0 custom validators:
>   https://web.archive.org/web/20110928154550/http://zadasnotes.blogspot.com/2010/12/rails-3-validation-using-parent-models.html

Comment: link to the blog is down.

Comment: updated it to link to internet archives of the page.

Answer (score 0):

When this is intepreted the class doesn't know what the project object is. And such validates can't be added dynamically. You can do the following

```
   def valiate
     unless (1..(project.effort)).member? effort
       errors.add :effort, "must be within 1 to #{project.effort}"
     end
   end
```

Comment: this is assuming you have a relationship b/w Task and Project model, each task effort should be within the range of its project's effort

Comment: I finally got a chance to try it out. Somehow your suggestion did not work for me. It was still not validating the change. I ended up doing the validation in a callback and throwing an exception if it is not valid. The only drawback is that the controller has to catch the exception.